# Lexer that recognizes indented blocks

Tags: python, compiler-construction, whitespace, lexer

I want to write a compiler for a language that denotes program blocks with white spaces, like in Python. I prefer to do this in Python, but C++ is also an option. Is there an open-source lexer that can help me do this easily, for example by generating INDENT and DEDENT identifiers properly like the Python lexer does? A corresponding parser generator will be a plus.

Comment: This question is from almost ten years ago. I can't say I remember much. From the description though, this question prefers python and the  other one C.

Comment: To provide context for the above out of the blue comment, there was a question about this being a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413204/how-to-use-indentation-as-block-delimiters-with-bison-and-flex. The person closing this has deleted their question. FWIW, I don't think this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[LEPL](http://www.acooke.org/lepl/offside.html#offside-parsing-blocks-of-lines) is pure Python and supports offside parsing.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the perfect tool for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using something like lex, you can do it this way:

```
^[ \t]+              { int new_indent = count_indent(yytext);
                       if (new_indent > current_indent) {
                          current_indent = new_indent;
                          return INDENT;
                       } else if (new_indent < current_indent) {
                          current_indent = new_indent;
                          return DEDENT;
                       }
                       /* Else do nothing, and this way
                          you can essentially treat INDENT and DEDENT
                          as opening and closing braces. */
                     }
```

You may need a little additional logic, for example to ignore blank lines, and to automatically add a DEDENT at the end of the file if needed.

Presumably count_indent would take into account converting tabs to spaces according to a tab-stop value.

I don't know about lexer/parser generators for Python, but what I posted should work with lex/flex, and you can hook it up to yacc/bison to create a parser. You could use C or C++ with those.

Comment: You have to be careful with this because you may need to add multiple DEDENT tokens at the start of a line, not just one.  Python suggests having a stack to maintain this.